# Cannot come up with the correct Kubeconfig when releasing an application to Kubernetes cluster in MS Azure

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Following this article, I was successfully able to create all builds within VSTS; however, I am unable to get past the VSTS release because of the Kubernetes endpoint

https://dgkanatsios.com/2017/05/29/creating-a-cicd-pipeline-on-azure-container-services-with-kubernetes-and-visual-studio-team-services/

I am trying to enter the correct contents for the Kubeconfig, but the files is never accepted

I did try to access the config file within the Azure cloud shell in the ~/.kube/ folder (with the vi editor) but the file is not accepted

Also, I ran a command "kubectl config view" and pasted the contents, but I would an error message saying "no kind 'Config' is registered for version V1"

Is there anything straightforward that I am missing?

Thank you very much for your generous support

Comment: Try to download the config file through [az acs kubernetes get-credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acs/kubernetes#get-credentials)
command, related article: [Booting Kubernetes on Azure Container Service](https://deis.com/docs/workflow/quickstart/provider/azure-acs/boot/)

Comment: Thank  you very much for your help! I did run this command, and it did look like it ran successfully. However (I am very new to Azure), could you please let me know when it was downloaded to. It is not listed (the config) in the current directory. Again, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Actually I was able to obtain newly downloaded config file from the Kube folder and paste contents of those files into the kubeconfig section; hpowever, I did get another error message saying " [pos 1657]: json: error decoding base64 binary"  Is there something that I should trim?

Comment: What's the content of kubeconfig like? What's the result if you convert it to base64 by using [tools/convert.ts](https://github.com/TsuyoshiUshio/KubernetesTask)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did paste config file contents below. I will try to convert it later today

Comment: When did you get the pos 1657 error?

Comment: I got 1657 error when I initiated the Release pipe line process in the Visual Studio Team Services

Comment: Can you share the detailed build logs? The decoding error should not be caused by the config file.

Comment: Eddie, thank you for your comment. I did post the log starting from the line 92

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eddie - MSFT, thank you very much for your pointers!

I did find a cause of my trouble

The problem was is that once I would get the text from the VI editor of a config file, I would paste it into a notepad that would break the line and adding the new line characters

I used the TextPad instead where I was making sure that the encoded lines stay straight

After that all releases went fine and were successful

Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 1):

According to the logs you provided, there are some unexpected blank space characters in the config file which cause the illegal error. For example, after 179 bytes "XdXaGN". These blank space characters does not exist in the config file you provided before, so it could be added when you copy and then paste the content into service endpoint. Please check and remove them and then try again. I just list part of them in the screenshot.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The content of the file is

```
    apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tDQpNSUlETURDQ0FoaWdBd0lCQWdJSWV0NzVtaVNhQ0FNd0RRWUpLb1pJaHZjTkFRRUxCUUF3RXpFUk1BOEdBMVVFQXd3SVlXTnphemh6DQpZMkV3SGhjTk1UY3dPREUxTURBd01EQXdXaGN
OTVRrd09ERTFNREF3TURBd1dqQVRNUkV3RHdZRFZRUUREQWhoWTNOck9ITmpZVENDDQpBU0l3RFFZSktvWklodmNOQVFFQkJRQURnZ0VQQURDQ0FRb0NnZ0VCQUxBQ1lva3pIOHZpZUY3RDBHcHl4VDFXdHZFMkhEbGx2WmdBDQpRYjVQYTVEamdsc2VnVWovQmczVStrczZ6amVGbXN
pSXlWS1p5aVlSQnRsSlI5ZnB2R0xYZzhxOW4vNVE3MlM5dEhyVGVmZ1o2WWU5DQo0U1JrV1AxT053bXN0Sk00cHNCL0R5QU5kOERRYXFYb0hTT2FjdkRjM2lFTzhZc0IzRjBydzRrU2lMTVlwUnRBQlZEbFZsQW1KbERqDQpxQVJWd3pzWDN5aUtQL1poTEc3cjlqemhqbjVXalpYTjM
yN3hIdlo4bWNZWno3RytzcldqbmRsYzZEdGMwQ1ZFNWtPL2pGL0FpOHgwDQpmNzZJWUxlTk5CMFBpVzlwa1NadFZoNnYxUDY4UHFzTjZPVTUrS1NTNGFjaERDaDBuc1JVV1o3RjF6Rlh4RUxsNUZIaVQ0Mzk2dEdjDQpkMDhDQXdFQUFhT0JoekNCaERCQ0JnTlZIU01FT3pBNWdCVFR
TRXhHRUtJNklOVktFM2ZJaEwrY1RtK0N4S0VYcEJVd0V6RVJNQThHDQpBMVVFQXd3SVlXTnphemh6WTJHQ0NIcmUrWm9rbWdnRE1CMEdBMVVkRGdRV0JCVFRTRXhHRUtJNklOVktFM2ZJaEwrY1RtK0N4REFQDQpCZ05WSFJNQkFmOEVCVEFEQVFIL01BNEdBMVVkRHdFQi93UUVBd0l
DcERBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBQU9DQVFFQWNyMlA0bHgzDQpWMDdFQVpHK1VYQ2pPbWJpU3RXWlR2d2JNanRLN2JWT3BtYlhWV2F5SWNONUFKejBFejhJczBnY3Z5cEM3VjV3b3NoUldGa1Y0V3Q4DQpTMGFyUmppQWZBdmVKMUZQZ3FVYi9GTjd1Q05BTUxSRXZkMDBQaW51VkJ
uQk1jaVJiN1NsTmJqUkxvUWtaTGl1aFMzVnJtRURUQXBYDQpIYVI4c1lKVXNyeUFwODRoeExwWm5MU1Z3L1BGQittc3F6aU1iRnlTSjdNLzdYY29tUm5aSjdSa21QN2owN2p4ZWJYMmF0T21MKzdmDQovNUFBdzNQZDZCRTFVRHBINzJSYk1hS1pjTkc1dm1UdGFzS0tjTnBZRWR2R2V
ISEJRNmFoOG1mSC85eEMwalo4SzdOMWtCUmpQMWxpDQpkRUFYTkZQQU82RVp6RjBEZUhSdlRZeHJYS0hwY3c9PQ0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQ0K"
    server: https://myk8scluster-myresourcegroup2-b35f44mgmt.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com
  name: "myk8scluster-myresourcegroup2-b35f44mgmt"
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: "myk8scluster-myresourcegroup2-b35f44mgmt"
    user: "myk8scluster-myresourcegroup2-b35f44mgmt-admin"
  name: "myk8scluster-myresourcegroup2-b35f44mgmt"
current-context: "myk8scluster-myresourcegroup2-b35f44mgmt"
kind: Config
users:
- name: "myk8scluster-myresourcegroup2-b35f44mgmt-admin"
  user:
    client-certificate-data: "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tDQpNSUlEUkRDQ0FpeWdBd0lCQWdJSUtnNGYxa2x5bC80d0RRWUpLb1pJaHZjTkFRRUxCUUF3RXpFUk1BOEdBMVVFQXd3SVlXTnphemh6DQpZMkV3SGhjTk1UY3dPREUxTURBd01EQXdXaGNOTV
Rrd09ERTFNREF3TURBd1dqQVZNUk13RVFZRFZRUUREQXByZFdKbFkyOXVabWxuDQpNSUlCSWpBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRRUZBQU9DQVE4QU1JSUJDZ0tDQVFFQTA1clN2UXZqbCthcGlvOURnZTVuNkl1QWx3d1ZsVklSDQp1QVNQMTArWHZtSGxMOEVnK1k1dVFUY1NRUEphaGRxd1
k1NnBVWmFaMWFVUUpSV2V3QWhBTWtsdWpWaGdRazJKYXRDdkRQV0dGcXFRDQpSc2ZkNkZJa2MxUCsxNHI3SVA1eHo4cXJvejRMUDJNUUZZanpoVlIwVTI0d1BzdGhjSFliSDl6R1JPaW12dUFwdytMbnpnUlBEdHRZDQpUeWg1R0l0VExaQVBVZk1yVWRHZnR0SUE1V01JeTc4OWVrdH
doK3dTVU9TbXpPUzhYaDVQMG5tOEw3WW9Gb05iSFhrUFhMMG9VNE9tDQp4NEVRK3IydEZ0MGU2eExyNUY3U0hlbzJFd1ZnYjNIL1BudkErRjh2NnBTaDZtbHIvM1dFTGRMaW5zblFRSCtKSFNLYndrTk1ncTRWDQorZlFwTndJREFRQUJvNEdaTUlHV01FSUdBMVVkSXdRN01EbUFGTk
5JVEVZUW9qb2cxVW9UZDhpRXY1eE9iNExFb1Jla0ZUQVRNUkV3DQpEd1lEVlFRRERBaGhZM05yT0hOallZSUlldDc1bWlTYUNBTXdIUVlEVlIwT0JCWUVGSUFKTi8zNkgzWjcrbjE3TmkreXVaekJWRzlhDQpNQXdHQTFVZEV3RUIvd1FDTUFBd0RnWURWUjBQQVFIL0JBUURBZ1dnTU
JNR0ExVWRKUVFNTUFvR0NDc0dBUVVGQndNQ01BMEdDU3FHDQpTSWIzRFFFQkN3VUFBNElCQVFDSGFmdmh6cHZZR2g5emNlM1pISkZkc1JNb1RoUWhQWXJhUFMva0tkTzA2YU5aUVZmR2VvRENscktyDQpuRk9zQXZ2cGVDTnJTOVBFcW5oRFZpbGxudFFNNGI5L0dJb0ZmMU1ISTl2b3
A4c3JLM0pLL1Q0MEpONmJjMXRuSWhuMW0waWJoZmZ1DQpVZ2cvcnM5U0ppaUNsTWV3cDFhRnhET0FJVjI0bFBBcHovK2RrRWs1OFhkNVovOEtQTVQxN0UvVlduUTRid3FndTBvMFJRNGlJZTNSDQoyWGxNSEtXVXd3SCtOeXZXclRYQXFRSk0xejJndk10Yy8vRmtNYWhXVHBOUzJaMW
xkZ256ODh1RTBsWUV0MzE4VlhEMFdBMjFSTXZGDQp3OU5OZCtRMzFCR0FsbEJUd05hV0VSdXVWdlQ5Qnd0cjhvaDVTL3M2SnVFNHNJcG5INjZEYUZYcQ0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQ0K"
    client-key-data: "LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJJVkFURSBLRVktLS0tLQ0KTUlJRXBRSUJBQUtDQVFFQTA1clN2UXZqbCthcGlvOURnZTVuNkl1QWx3d1ZsVklSdUFTUDEwK1h2bUhsTDhFZw0KK1k1dVFUY1NRUEphaGRxd1k1NnBVWmFaMWFVUUpSV2V3QWhBTWtsdWpWaG
dRazJKYXRDdkRQV0dGcXFRUnNmZA0KNkZJa2MxUCsxNHI3SVA1eHo4cXJvejRMUDJNUUZZanpoVlIwVTI0d1BzdGhjSFliSDl6R1JPaW12dUFwdytMbg0KemdSUER0dFlUeWg1R0l0VExaQVBVZk1yVWRHZnR0SUE1V01JeTc4OWVrdHdoK3dTVU9TbXpPUzhYaDVQMG5tOA0KTDdZb0
ZvTmJIWGtQWEwwb1U0T214NEVRK3IydEZ0MGU2eExyNUY3U0hlbzJFd1ZnYjNIL1BudkErRjh2NnBTaA0KNm1sci8zV0VMZExpbnNuUVFIK0pIU0tid2tOTWdxNFYrZlFwTndJREFRQUJBb0lCQUZoTFYvZk9DQytQN2RxRg0KSVBRTVdJc3Qrb0FNYU0wZnE0a1BUajNYVmtmNGJUdF
o2THA0OWdSOFNEK1ZZTFJOcGlCTFNmZGpVZGxWd01EWQ0KbnA4ZVVqc3BiTm5Kc0pDNTdjY0dRS1MxcGplNi8reW81UzFWYVNRK1BpNE9MZTk4ZkZ6cUFtaGhNU3hIMTZSRQ0KdXVnOWJ6U0kyOVMzNUhhYXNZTEFDbk1pYU1GbjRZSEtsN3JqNmZuWGE3MWo4MmVpb0luS01kQU4wSX
FJNG9KVw0KclExdlFoQ1NzSjdvcStCS0JRZ0dQZjVuRVZqYW5zWksrdktLOTBsLzE3SDJDZTBXUzhIcFhqbG9sNFE2bC95SQ0KcTF0OER2bnB1NFdmNVYwN0UrSVhjMmw5MmtDNlRVeFRqSXE4RjlheUp4akp6QnA1YmhpR3VEQ0ZWdkI1Zmx0UA0KcHFUTHpnRUNnWUVBN055OFZ1K0
twclk0SXdKT1VyZFd0TW1rbnRhczRpTXlvN3A2cWhYb2N1ay9lZms3NmQxOA0KZkFmdW51dGhUN1NBNzZrVTdOa3hVaDd3ZFdEZTIzcXpiQkZTcHBOUENBRU1yMjJZdGplWXp6Y0MweGROZVkwNQ0KWDBGeE9lUjQxbjFNOGdwUmJibnlLYWxOenJ2K1JKVlFuS0traVdHV2FKZ1dqWT
F3QVdWV2k3Y0NnWUVBNUxPcA0KVURSY2NRcHJHV1V4Nm9IZ2ZwZytZdGxPRzBVYzNrTEVJQ2dxdklmYWsvT1BBUGx0Nklqcy9NV3BqQUZ4M2VXag0KTHZZQW9sTVpvc2oyU0psTUJwWkk0OTVoVWg1Wm04UkNlMFhiNzMrdjc5UW92T3lMZExWbFBrc205YzJBNmMzQg0KbUV4NE5Xa0
hLNHBzbWtDZC9LOEVVR0U3YndydzB3OFpVOWRxVG9FQ2dZRUEzay9EZWZrMGNvcWVuOFUvVEFXRw0KSFFNUlBvQVJIZUtaV2ZEaHhwZnZaME1pNzlHTWVWRUgwTVlGSWlXY1hSbjIxbm9sQ0xSRnhXVUNuYmpCRXREVQ0KYkQ3S0MweEJwaXFPQkcxaUlzeUY0UjhweUlTYms5V0lIcT
ZtbmdhaG4vZFU2K3ZoUjVKNkJyNUFLQ1JzWDJTaA0KbDVKVHlobk0rUGllV2xlQTQ5NkFYM3NDZ1lFQWx6M28zazJDUkk4clBHUWJtb1hCUEhiWjZ1emlKazZTUkxuSw0Ka2FsK2VhY3QrV0c4VkZ5ZlBvUXVsUXJ5a00venlWYXZqOExIc0pGY0JyYjNpQk00bjdLTENZWnF2YStzZX
NKVA0KWk1wU0pCUkErVTFJazRlcXdjZWo2SW95ZmFNbGVYakVhajlIejZwaFAzNFBUQU1uZDQ4V1AwSE4yQ1ZZRlh1Sw0KdUZOZ3pnRUNnWUVBdm1YeHVPUmtEWGR2Vm5nZXM0Y2hNYkNJeHl6Uk9RRUpaaUFWaTdXSTI1YVREbWdDZlJLNA0KYnRoSWdDa3F0bjdYRWdvRDRTTHBMej
NkL3o4UjQ1cGxpVHJ0N25Sakp0UHB0RUdMaHhpbWttdzN6RnVSL0FIMQ0KM1dWWXFyelB3bWZaNHMyWGlRbFhnOHo3YmhEU1N6RU9BcW45eVRKTkJkRWVOV2h2c1NuOWhJVT0NCi0tLS0tRU5EIFJTQSBQUklWQVRFIEtFWS0tLS0tDQoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the log that starts at the line 92

> 2017-08-29T14:40:36.4663420Z Download all required tasks.
>   2017-08-29T14:40:36.5194520Z Downloading task: Kubernetes
>   2017-08-29T14:40:37.4530470Z ##[section]Finishing: Initialize Job
>   2017-08-29T14:40:38.4092780Z ##[section]Starting: Download Artifacts
>   2017-08-29T14:40:38.6282060Z Downloading artifact
>   2017-08-29T14:40:38.6684580Z Creating artifacts directory: /opt/vsts/work/r1/a
>   2017-08-29T14:40:38.6966830Z Created artifacts directory: /opt/vsts/work/r1/a
>   2017-08-29T14:40:38.8251540Z Starting artifacts download...
>   2017-08-29T14:40:38.8797600Z Downloading linked artifact KubernetesCluster of type Build...
>   2017-08-29T14:40:38.8999340Z Ensuring artifact folder /opt/vsts/work/r1/a/KubernetesCluster exists and is clean.
>   2017-08-29T14:40:38.9380610Z Preparing to get the list of available artifacts from build
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.2194670Z Preparing to download artifact: deploy
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.2396450Z Artifact Type: ServerDrop
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.2560460Z Downloading artifact from file container: #/2190836/deploy to target: /opt/vsts/work/r1/a/KubernetesCluster/deploy
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.2877200Z Parallel download limit: 4
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.3035960Z Download buffer size: 8192
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.5527930Z Caching items under 'deploy' in the file container...
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.6449920Z Caching complete. (75 ms)
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.6734790Z Downloading file /opt/vsts/work/r1/a/KubernetesCluster/deploy/deploy.yaml
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.9513700Z Download complete.
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.9685490Z 1 placed file(s): 1 downloaded, 0 empty
>   2017-08-29T14:40:39.9840720Z 1 MB downloaded at 6 KB/sec. Download time: 00:00:00.2815253.
>   2017-08-29T14:40:40.0000810Z Downloaded linked artifact KubernetesCluster
>   2017-08-29T14:40:40.0158320Z Finished artifacts download
>   2017-08-29T14:40:40.0315320Z Downloading commits
>   2017-08-29T14:40:40.0950300Z ##[section]Finishing: Download Artifacts
>   2017-08-29T14:40:40.9837380Z ##[section]Starting: kubectl apply
>   2017-08-29T14:40:41.0806260Z ==============================================================================
>   2017-08-29T14:40:41.0982230Z Task         : Deploy to Kubernetes
>   2017-08-29T14:40:41.1149960Z Description  : Deploy, configure, update your Kubernetes cluster in Azure Container Service by running kubectl commands.
>   2017-08-29T14:40:41.1312870Z Version      : 0.1.3
>   2017-08-29T14:40:41.1472790Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
>   2017-08-29T14:40:41.1631820Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851275)
>   2017-08-29T14:40:41.1792190Z ==============================================================================
>   2017-08-29T14:40:46.5099920Z [command]/opt/vsts/work/_temp/kubectlTask/1504017644472/kubectl --kubeconfig /opt/vsts/work/_temp/kubectlTask/1504017644472/config apply -f /opt/vsts/work/r1/a/KubernetesCluster/deploy/deploy.yaml
>   2017-08-29T14:40:46.5292110Z error: Error loading config file "/opt/vsts/work/_temp/kubectlTask/1504017644472/config": [pos 1657]: json: error decoding base64 binary 'LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tDQpNSUlETURDQ0FoaWdBd0lCQWdJSWV0NzVtaVNhQ0FNd0RRWUpLb1pJaHZjTkFRRUxCUUF3RXpFUk1BOEdBMVVFQXd3SVlXTnphemh6DQpZMkV3SGhjTk1UY3dPREUxTURBd01EQXdXaGN OTVRrd09ERTFNREF3TURBd1dqQVRNUkV3RHdZRFZRUUREQWhoWTNOck9ITmpZVENDDQpBU0l3RFFZSktvWklodmNOQVFFQkJRQURnZ0VQQURDQ0FRb0NnZ0VCQUxBQ1lva3pIOHZpZUY3RDBHcHl4VDFXdHZFMkhEbGx2WmdBDQpRYjVQYTVEamdsc2VnVWovQmczVStrczZ6amVGbXN pSXlWS1p5aVlSQnRsSlI5ZnB2R0xYZzhxOW4vNVE3MlM5dEhyVGVmZ1o2WWU5DQo0U1JrV1AxT053bXN0Sk00cHNCL0R5QU5kOERRYXFYb0hTT2FjdkRjM2lFTzhZc0IzRjBydzRrU2lMTVlwUnRBQlZEbFZsQW1KbERqDQpxQVJWd3pzWDN5aUtQL1poTEc3cjlqemhqbjVXalpYTjM yN3hIdlo4bWNZWno3RytzcldqbmRsYzZEdGMwQ1ZFNWtPL2pGL0FpOHgwDQpmNzZJWUxlTk5CMFBpVzlwa1NadFZoNnYxUDY4UHFzTjZPVTUrS1NTNGFjaERDaDBuc1JVV1o3RjF6Rlh4RUxsNUZIaVQ0Mzk2dEdjDQpkMDhDQXdFQUFhT0JoekNCaERCQ0JnTlZIU01FT3pBNWdCVFR TRXhHRUtJNklOVktFM2ZJaEwrY1RtK0N4S0VYcEJVd0V6RVJNQThHDQpBMVVFQXd3SVlXTnphemh6WTJHQ0NIcmUrWm9rbWdnRE1CMEdBMVVkRGdRV0JCVFRTRXhHRUtJNklOVktFM2ZJaEwrY1RtK0N4REFQDQpCZ05WSFJNQkFmOEVCVEFEQVFIL01BNEdBMVVkRHdFQi93UUVBd0l DcERBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBQU9DQVFFQWNyMlA0bHgzDQpWMDdFQVpHK1VYQ2pPbWJpU3RXWlR2d2JNanRLN2JWT3BtYlhWV2F5SWNONUFKejBFejhJczBnY3Z5cEM3VjV3b3NoUldGa1Y0V3Q4DQpTMGFyUmppQWZBdmVKMUZQZ3FVYi9GTjd1Q05BTUxSRXZkMDBQaW51VkJ uQk1jaVJiN1NsTmJqUkxvUWtaTGl1aFMzVnJtRURUQXBYDQpIYVI4c1lKVXNyeUFwODRoeExwWm5MU1Z3L1BGQittc3F6aU1iRnlTSjdNLzdYY29tUm5aSjdSa21QN2owN2p4ZWJYMmF0T21MKzdmDQovNUFBdzNQZDZCRTFVRHBINzJSYk1hS1pjTkc1dm1UdGFzS0tjTnBZRWR2R2V ISEJRNmFoOG1mSC85eEMwalo4SzdOMWtCUmpQMWxpDQpkRUFYTkZQQU82RVp6RjBEZUhSdlRZeHJYS0hwY3c9PQ0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQ0K': illegal base64 data at input byte 179
>   2017-08-29T14:40:46.6025270Z ##[error]error: Error loading config file "/opt/vsts/work/_temp/kubectlTask/1504017644472/config": [pos 1657]: json: error decoding base64 binary 'LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tLS0tDQpNSUlETURDQ0FoaWdBd0lCQWdJSWV0NzVtaVNhQ0FNd0RRWUpLb1pJaHZjTkFRRUxCUUF3RXpFUk1BOEdBMVVFQXd3SVlXTnphemh6DQpZMkV3SGhjTk1UY3dPREUxTURBd01EQXdXaGN OTVRrd09ERTFNREF3TURBd1dqQVRNUkV3RHdZRFZRUUREQWhoWTNOck9ITmpZVENDDQpBU0l3RFFZSktvWklodmNOQVFFQkJRQURnZ0VQQURDQ0FRb0NnZ0VCQUxBQ1lva3pIOHZpZUY3RDBHcHl4VDFXdHZFMkhEbGx2WmdBDQpRYjVQYTVEamdsc2VnVWovQmczVStrczZ6amVGbXN pSXlWS1p5aVlSQnRsSlI5ZnB2R0xYZzhxOW4vNVE3MlM5dEhyVGVmZ1o2WWU5DQo0U1JrV1AxT053bXN0Sk00cHNCL0R5QU5kOERRYXFYb0hTT2FjdkRjM2lFTzhZc0IzRjBydzRrU2lMTVlwUnRBQlZEbFZsQW1KbERqDQpxQVJWd3pzWDN5aUtQL1poTEc3cjlqemhqbjVXalpYTjM yN3hIdlo4bWNZWno3RytzcldqbmRsYzZEdGMwQ1ZFNWtPL2pGL0FpOHgwDQpmNzZJWUxlTk5CMFBpVzlwa1NadFZoNnYxUDY4UHFzTjZPVTUrS1NTNGFjaERDaDBuc1JVV1o3RjF6Rlh4RUxsNUZIaVQ0Mzk2dEdjDQpkMDhDQXdFQUFhT0JoekNCaERCQ0JnTlZIU01FT3pBNWdCVFR TRXhHRUtJNklOVktFM2ZJaEwrY1RtK0N4S0VYcEJVd0V6RVJNQThHDQpBMVVFQXd3SVlXTnphemh6WTJHQ0NIcmUrWm9rbWdnRE1CMEdBMVVkRGdRV0JCVFRTRXhHRUtJNklOVktFM2ZJaEwrY1RtK0N4REFQDQpCZ05WSFJNQkFmOEVCVEFEQVFIL01BNEdBMVVkRHdFQi93UUVBd0l DcERBTkJna3Foa2lHOXcwQkFRc0ZBQU9DQVFFQWNyMlA0bHgzDQpWMDdFQVpHK1VYQ2pPbWJpU3RXWlR2d2JNanRLN2JWT3BtYlhWV2F5SWNONUFKejBFejhJczBnY3Z5cEM3VjV3b3NoUldGa1Y0V3Q4DQpTMGFyUmppQWZBdmVKMUZQZ3FVYi9GTjd1Q05BTUxSRXZkMDBQaW51VkJ uQk1jaVJiN1NsTmJqUkxvUWtaTGl1aFMzVnJtRURUQXBYDQpIYVI4c1lKVXNyeUFwODRoeExwWm5MU1Z3L1BGQittc3F6aU1iRnlTSjdNLzdYY29tUm5aSjdSa21QN2owN2p4ZWJYMmF0T21MKzdmDQovNUFBdzNQZDZCRTFVRHBINzJSYk1hS1pjTkc1dm1UdGFzS0tjTnBZRWR2R2V ISEJRNmFoOG1mSC85eEMwalo4SzdOMWtCUmpQMWxpDQpkRUFYTkZQQU82RVp6RjBEZUhSdlRZeHJYS0hwY3c9PQ0KLS0tLS1FTkQgQ0VSVElGSUNBVEUtLS0tLQ0K': illegal base64 data at input byte 179
>   2017-08-29T14:40:46.6583100Z ##[error]/opt/vsts/work/_temp/kubectlTask/1504017644472/kubectl failed with return code: 1
>   2017-08-29T14:40:46.7240620Z ##[section]Finishing: kubectl apply
>   2017-08-29T14:40:46.8777480Z ##[section]Finishing: Release